# Пустые файлы по FTP в VS code на linux mint

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, linux-mint

Я использую linux mint (mate), подключаюсь через стандартный файловый менеджер caja  по ftp, могу редактировать файлы. 
НО когда используя это подключение,  я открываю файлы в VS code, они пустые. Когда использую например Atom - всё работает, но Atom мне не подходит. Помогите, пожалуйста.
Проблему удалось частично решить используя curlftpfs, монтируя ftp как локальную папку. Но это работает слишком медленно

Comment: вы что хотите, чтобы исходники в одном месте лежали? может лучше использовать svn или git для синхронизации?

Comment: @PavelGridin, Я сайт делаю на wp. И редактировать php файлы мне нужно сразу на сервере. Для меня это гораздо комфортнее в vs code.

Comment: Правильно! Даёшь прямое редактирование продакшна и пятилетку за один день!

Comment: @ДмитрийБоженко, а что на сервере нельзя работать через x2go или vnc, или запустить у себя xserver и vs code с сервера запускать у себя через putty?

Comment: @PavelGridin , вы, возможно, несколько неверно поняли ситуацию. Есть хостнинг. Залил я туда вордпресс и файлы php редачу там. Подключаюсь к хостингу по FTP. И со своего ноута на котором у меня linux и vs code редактирую файлы

Comment: @0andriy, да не, это тестовый хостинг)

Comment: @ДмитрийБоженко, а, я думал свой сервер

Comment: может, это поможет https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mkloubert.vscode-remote-workspace